# Cannot subscript a value of type '[Double]' with an argument of type 'Double'

Tags: swift

I would like to pass an array of a selected number as a `Double` However i get this error **Cannot subscript a value of type '[Double]' with an argument of type 'Double'**

Coud someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in Advance!

```
import UIKit

class SelectAttributesViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var kitPickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var reactionVolumeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfSampleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var volumeOfTemplateDNATextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!






    let kits = ["kit 1"]
    let pArray: [Double] = [10,20,50]

    var currentValue = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.numberOfSampleTextField.delegate = self
        self.volumeOfTemplateDNATextField.delegate = self
        kitPickerView.dataSource = self
        kitPickerView.delegate = self

        //slider.addTarget(self, action: "reactionVolumeSlider", for: .valueChanged)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func pcrSliderInterval() {
        slider.minimumValue = 0
        slider.maximumValue = Float(pArray.count)
        slider.isContinuous = false

    }


    @IBAction func reactionVolumeSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {

        currentValue = pArray[Double(sender.value)] // This is where I get the error
        reactionVolumeLabel.text = "\(currentValue) μL"


    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return kits.count

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if row == 0{ print(kits[row])

        }

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return kits[row]
    }
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let oldText = textField.text, let r = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
            return true
        }

        let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: r, with: string)
        let isNumeric = newText.isEmpty || (Double(newText) != nil)
        let numberOfDots = newText.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1

        let numberOfDecimalDigits: Int
        if let dotIndex = newText.firstIndex(of: ".") {
            numberOfDecimalDigits = newText.distance(from: dotIndex, to: newText.endIndex) - 1
        } else {
            numberOfDecimalDigits = 0
        }

        return isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 2
    }
    func createAlert (title: String, message: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (Action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)






    }




    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let masterMix = segue.destination as! MasterMixTableViewController
        masterMix.numberOfSamples = numberOfSampleTextField.text!
        masterMix.volumeOfTemplateDna = volumeOfTemplateDNATextField.text!
        masterMix.reactionVolumeInt = currentValue
        //masterMix.waterVolumeText = getWaterVolumeLabelText()

       // let masterMix = segue.destination as! MasterMixTableViewController
       // masterMix.loadViewIfNeeded()
       // masterMix.numberOfSamples = String(numberOfSampleTextField.text)
       // masterMix.waterVolumeLabel!.text = String(Double(numberOfSampleTextField.text!)! * 50
       // masterMix.bufferVolumeLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSampleTextField.text!)! * 10)
       // masterMix.dNTPsVolumeLabel.text = numberOfSampleTextField!.text // done
       // masterMix.forwardPrimerLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSampleTextField.text!)! * 2.5) //done
       // masterMix.reversePrimerLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSampleTextField.text!)! * 2.5) //done
       // masterMix.dnaPolymeraseLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSampleTextField.text!)! * 0.5) //done

        //answer.text = String(Int(entry.text)! * 2)

    }

    @IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if numberOfSampleTextField.text != ""{
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "masterMixSegue", sender: self)
        }

    }




}
```

Comment: What would you expect `pArray[0.5]` to do? As far as the compiler is concerned, that's what you're asking of it, and it has no idea what to do about it. So it errors out, and insists that you provide integer indices only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say

```
pArray[Double(sender.value)]
```

You need an Int. You would need

```
pArray[Int(sender.value)]
```

Except that that is unlikely to get you the desired index and you will probably crash at runtime. You will need to calculate the right index. I have no idea what you think is the relationship between your continuous slider values and the discrete indexes of an array, so I can’t say more. Maybe a slider was the wrong choice of interface?

Answer (score 2):

The error says that an array cannot be subscripted by a Double.

The index type of Array is `Int`

```
pArray[Int(sender.value)]
```

And be aware that your maximum value will cause an out-of-range crash.